# How to define $A\uparrow B$ with a universal property as well as $A\oplus B$, $A\times B$, $A^B$ in category theory?

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, tetration, hyperoperation

In category theory there are definitions for $A\oplus B$, $A\times B$ and $A^B$ via universal properties. I wonder if it is possible to isolate a particular universal property to represent the [tetration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) of $A,B$ which we denote it by $A\uparrow B$. Intuitively $A\uparrow B$ is $\underbrace {A^{A^{A^{.^{.^{.}}}}}}_{B-times}$.

> **Question:** What is the category theoretic definition of $A\uparrow B$ object?

---

**Remark:** Regarding the comments on finding some examples of tetration of two mathematical objects, I think this is exactly the difficulty of the problem. It seems there is no intuition about tetration and other hyperoperators out of number theory. But I think there is an "implicit" way to describe such an object in category theory via the notions of "exponentiation" and "limit" objects. In fact I hope one may give me a purely abstract way of defining tetration of two objects via categorical constructions that could be used as a base of definition for tetration of two objects in different contexts.

Comment: First you need some examples.  Tetration of groups.  Tetration of vector spaces.  And so on.  In particular, say what you mean by $B$-times where $B$ is a group...

Comment: I hate tetration.

Comment: I'm not aware of any reasonably general definition of $A \uparrow B$ where $B$ is anything other than a non-negative integer; categorically this corresponds to taking iterated exponential objects. I think in general tetration is a pretty unnatural operation to look at, and the lack of an obvious answer to this categorical question is one of the more compelling pieces of evidence in favor of that.

Comment: Half a year ago I also asked a question about the number-analogy for categories and in particular the exponentiation operation [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/847133/how-are-the-cardinalities-of-the-object-images-of-adjoint-functors-related). The exponential object isn't a limit, so I don't think there'll be a good limit which end up as $A^{A^{...}}$. I'd ask myself the question what properties the number $a^{a^{a^{...}}}$ has, which can be expressed more polynomial. Maybe you find some analogous object then. What's a combinatorial problem with the answer being the tetration?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan About *unnaturality* of tetration, I *was* agree with you but as well as I learned more about it from recursion theory in connection with [Ackermann function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) and [Chaitin's incompleteness theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_incompleteness_theorem), I found out that it is a really natural continuation of exponentiation operator and at least as useful as successor, addition, multiplication and exponentiation with a really deep and completely unknown theory. It seems tetration is a **forgotten operator** in our maths.

Comment: @AliSadeghDaghighi: *at least as useful as addition*!!

Comment: @NikolajK Consider our mathematical world without exponentiation. Many deep theorems of number theory, differentiatl equations, analysis, calculus, and other parts of maths have a neat formulation in terms of exponentiation. In many aspects "exponentiation" and "tetration" are similar and very unnatural with respect to addition and multiplication. For example note that both are non-commutative but addition and multiplication commute. It seems concluding the unntaturality of tetration just because we have no intuition about it, is as same as discussing on unnaturality of 4-dimensional spaces.

Comment: @NikolajK Regarding your subtle observation that *"exponentiation is not a limit of multiplication"* and so *"we should not expect that tetration be a limit of exponentiation"*, I am completely agree with you and this makes the problem of **"finding a true interpretation for tetration"** even more complicated. It seems your suggested approach on searching for a **combinatorial property** which have a solution in terms of tetration is the correct and only possible approach.

Comment: @NikolajK See my question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1012260/what-combinatorial-quantity-the-tetration-of-two-natural-numbers-represents) and also [Graham's number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number).

Comment: I see [someone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Sweeney_%28game_developer%29) asked a related question 15 years ago [here](http://marc.info/?t=123386843000043&r=1&w=2). Write him a mail and ask if something came of it.

Comment: @NikolajK Interesting! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a,b$ be objects of a closed symmetric monoidal category. Then $a^b$ may be written for the internal hom $\underline{\hom}(b,a)$. In fact, then we have the usual laws such as $a^{b+c}=a^b \times a^c$ and $(a^b)^c = a^{b \times c}$.

Now let us iterate this. $a^a = \underline{\hom}(a,a)$, $a^{a^a} = \underline{\hom}(\underline{\hom}(a,a),a)$, etc. We can define $^{n} a=a^{a^{a^{a^\dotsc}}}$ for every $n < \omega$. Assume that every object is dualizable (for example, consider the category of finite-dimensional vector spaces over some field), so that $a^b = b^* \otimes a$. Then one shows by induction that
$$^n a = \left\{\begin{array}{c}(a^*)^{\otimes \frac{n}{2}} \otimes a^{\otimes \frac{n}{2}} & n \text{ even} \\ (a^*)^{\otimes \frac{n-1}{2}} \otimes a^{\otimes \frac{n+1}{2}} & n \text{ odd}\end{array}\right.$$
This case distinction indicates that it is impossible to give a natural definition of $^b a$ for objects $a,b$.

Comment: Thanks for your interesting answer. Would you please explain more on your final claim that *"this case distinction indicates that it is impossible to give a natural definition of $a\uparrow b$ for objects $a,b$"*? However I think tetration of $a$, $b$ should not be considered as limit of exponentiations.

Comment: I think that every sensible definition of $^{b} a$ should satisfy $^{n \cdot 1} b = {}^{n} a$ for $n < \omega$, where $n \cdot 1$ is a direct sum of $n$ copies of $1$. In the case of f.d. vector spaces this means that $^{b} a$ should be isomorphic to $^{n} a$ when $n = \dim(b)$. But it is weird that this depends on the parity of $\dim(b)$!

Comment: Here is a related problem: Is there a natural (in particular, functorial) definition of $b \cdot a$ which satisfies $(n \cdot 1) \cdot a = a^{\otimes n}$? I don't think so, because $n \times m$-matrices don't induce linear maps $a^{\otimes m} \to a^{\otimes n}$. In the case of tetration, it is even worse.

Comment: What about defining a functor $\mathfrak T:\mathcal C\to\mathcal C$ a tetration functor  for that  closed symmetric monoidal category iff there exists an object $a\in\mathcal C$ such that $$\underline{\rm hom}(\mathfrak T(b),a)\simeq \mathfrak T(b+1)$$maybe using a coproduct or the terminal object?